# How to get lists of ERC20, ERC721 and ERC827 tokens from Ethereum address

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, erc20

How can I get lists of ERC20, ERC721 and ERC827 tokens in a particular Ethereum wallet address? Also I would like to be able to get the name, symbol, logo, and balance from the main net.

Answer (score 1):

ERC-721 includes an optional interface (optional means the contract implementor can choose if they want to implement it) to enumerate tokens owned by a specific account.

Su Squares implements this feature, but few other contracts do it.

You can use tools like Etherscan, Enjinx Blockchain Explorer or write your own interface to a Ethereum JSON RPC host to collect the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do a total data dive per address. I think you have to go the other way around, meaning looking if a contract contains a certain token. For the major tokens like [EOS](https://etherscan.io/token/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0), this should be easy with MEW.

But if you're looking for some obscure tokens such as the ones below, you probably have to add them to MEW manually to check:

- [Crap Coin (CRP)](https://etherscan.io/token/0x9d42f7654da7bbf79d0a08373290aa89f60d918c)
- [Ingrid Is a Horrible Human Coin (iHH)](https://etherscan.io/token/0x51696e028e0fe5416481c28cf1a2626d43680751)
- [Banana Coin](https://etherscan.io/token/0x4c08293d7f707cb7af4b32093c4f1ff5cca8255f)